# Get productID of the product being edited in Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way, in Magento, to get the productID of the product currently being edited on the Admin backend?

I found this:

```
Mage::registry('current_product');
```

but it doesn't seem to get the one being edited.

Edit: If it makes any difference, I'm trying to get it from an extension listening for the event:

```
catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after
```

Answer (score 4):

The current product's ID is in the URL. You can retrieve it as a parameter like so:

```
$productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

If you want to load the product as an object, store that ID and use

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Edit: It looks like you're using an observer. The observer file itself I assume does not extend any part of Magento. (Is this the file? http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php) Try obtaining the action and getting the request that way

```
$action = $observer->getAction();
$productId = $action->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Comment: I'm don't think that's working.  This statement:     Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

doesn't print anything

And,   doing a $model->load on it returns a blank product object.

Comment: I have an extension that has an Observer for "catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after".  The code is in  /Model/Observer.php.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, as should `Mage::registry('product')`, as long as it is requested after `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController::_initProduct()` is called.

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')` should also work.

**Edit based on event**

The event being observed is dispatched in response to a JS-originated request. The controller action is unaware of the calling context, and there is no product registered in the registry. Logging the request params or possibly the referrer may give insight.

Comment: I don't think that's working. This statement: Mage::log(Mage::registry('product'));   

doesn't print anything

Comment: Updated answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Would it be possible for my module to have two Observers,  one listening for one "further back" that would have the product information, and the current one listening for the image upload?  Could the observer listening further back somehow store the information for the upload listener?

Comment: You are encountering the by-design statelessness of HTTP requests. You could store this in a cookie or in the admin session, both of which seem like overkill. I would resort to this only if I had proven that `$_REQUEST` does not contain identifying information. Beyond this, there is a downstream process which must be triggered by JS which *does* connect this field with its entity.